# @input only updating one component variable in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I have two components.

1. Project calendar view component - parent
2. Project list view  component - child for project calendar

In Project calendar I have variable like

```
@Input() projects : Project[] = [];
```

In Project list view  component I have variable like

```
@Input()  projects:  Project[] = [];
```

Passing the data from Project calendar view component to Project list view  component by `<app-project [projects]="projects"></app-project>`.

In project list page implemented the project delete functionality with the below code. splice apply only for project list page not in  Project calendar component.

```
  removeProject(project: Project) {
    var index: number = this.projects.indexOf(project);
    if (index > -1) {
       this.projects.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
```

In Project calendar view component deleted project still showing. It's deleting only in  Project list view component variable.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Delete happening only on Project list view  component not updating the Project calendar view component variable projects.

Comment: How you detect that? There is some forEach for projects inside child component?

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. I created one, that matches your description, but doesn't reproduce the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/qaAYe2wQtV5DOObMXFGZ?p=preview

Comment: Consider reading this: http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-ngfor/. Maybe you might need trackBy.

Comment: @JB Nizet : Delete action will be in child component as per my requirement.

Comment: Butting in here... @Govindaraj Did you check JB's plunker, the deletion is happening in child...